# How to add global route prefix in asp.net core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

Legacy .net core frameworks used `UseMvc()` for adding global route prefix. How to make it for `asp.net core 3` without `UseMvc()` ?

Comment: Asp.net core 3.0 uses `app.UseEndpoints()`, what global route prefix do you want to implement?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could refer to below demo in asp.net core 3.0 to set global route prefix with api version.You could set any prefix as you like by changing `services.AddControllersWithViews(o => { o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}"); });`

1.Create a custom `MvcOptionsExtensions`

```cs
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, IRouteTemplateProvider routeAttribute)
    {
        opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention(routeAttribute));
    }

    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, string 
    prefix)
    {
        opts.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute(prefix));
    }
}

public class RoutePrefixConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    private readonly AttributeRouteModel _routePrefix;

    public RoutePrefixConvention(IRouteTemplateProvider route)
    {
        _routePrefix = new AttributeRouteModel(route);
    }

    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var selector in application.Controllers.SelectMany(c => c.Selectors))
        {
            if (selector.AttributeRouteModel != null)
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(_routePrefix, selector.AttributeRouteModel);
            }
            else
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = _routePrefix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Register in Startup.cs( you need to install package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/4.0.0-preview8.19405.7) ,current version for 3.0 is 4.0.0-preview8.19405.7)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //MVC service registration
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration
    services.AddControllersWithViews(o = >{
        o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}");
    });

    services.AddApiVersioning(o = >o.ReportApiVersions = true);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints = >{
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

3.Controller:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1")]
[ApiVersion("2")]
[Route("test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("version"), MapToApiVersion("1")]
    public IActionResult GetV1()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("Version One");
    }
}
```

4.Result

Calling `/api/v1/test/version` results in "Version One".

Answer (score 20):

I solved this in 3.1 with just the below in my startup `Configure()`:

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I found a few variations on this here... https://forums.servicestack.net/t/net-core-3-1-custom-api-path-metadata/8155 but those didn't work for me either.

Comment: Because it's a middleware the order you add it matters. It works for me in core 3.1 if I add it right before the `UseRouting()` middleware. If added afterwards it will not work.

Comment: This won't work if there's no explicit call to `UseRouting()` because then it's executed at the start of the pipeline, at least that's the case in .NET 6.  

Please refer to this issue for the right order of calls for this solution to work https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38448#issuecomment-970882631

Answer (score 7):

As @alastairtree answered you can use `app.UsePathBase` to achieve this.

You need to place this call before registering the middleware that needs to be prefixed.

If you need to register other middleware after that, that should not be prefixed, you can reset the prefix to `/`.

Full example:

```cs
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/"));
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: At this moment I'm actually not sure whether this works correctly. In any case a downside of `UsePathBase` seems to be that both the prefixed and non-prefixed paths result in the endpoint. This may or may not be a problem, depending on your use case.

Personally I switched to adding the prefix to every controller: `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Answer (score 2):

How to add global route prefix in asp.net core 6
Still works:

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api/service"));
app.UseRouting();
```