# IApplicationBuilder.UseBasePath odd behaviour?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

I am trying to add versioning to my web api and after reading asp .net core documentation it seemed that IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase could serve to this purpose. And, it really does but with a quirk. The api can still be accesed without adding the versioning path.

As an example, I use this to add an v1 path to my api:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpAccesor)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/api/v1");
    ....
}
```

Now I am able to access my cars endpoint by using http://www...com/api/v1/cars or by using http://www...com/cars.

The cars controller routing is setup this way:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DriversController : ControllerBase
{
  ....
}
```

So, is this how it works? Is there any possibility to just allow paths with the corresponding versioning path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per document [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-3.1) extracts the specified path from a request. If it is not provided in the request then it will be ignored.

It's useful with micro-service architecture where multiple micro-services are hosted with docker and Load Balancer can route the request base on a request path. so it not required to do any URL mapping or re-write the path.

Hope this would clear your queries.

.Net core 2.2 versioning:
we used **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning** NuGet package OR [GIT](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) for our project and it's in .net core 2.2. It's required some set in Setup.cs -> ConfigureService method file and then you can use in your controller i.e.  `[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]`

Setup.cs -> ConfigureService

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });
```

Comment: Ok, I see, I overlooked this part. So, Is there any way to add the versioning part of the path (/api/v1) without modifying all the controllers routes. I mean, I need an easy way to be able to change endpoints urls based on a versioning string. If tomorrow I want to change /api/v1 to /api/v2 I don't want to change that in every controller routing attribute :/.

Comment: @Notbad, we used **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning** NuGet package for our project and it's in .net core 2.2. It's required some set in Setup.cs -> ConfigureService method file and then you can use in your controller i.e.  `[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]`
*Setup.cs -> ConfigureService*:
`services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the order in which I did the UsePathBase.  If I put one line later it doesn't work.

```
  app.UsePathBase("/MyPath");
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
```

Comment: To clarify, this code snipped demonstrates the correct ordering.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enforce a **global prefix route** with a **global versioning** to your controllers you can check the answer of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340979/how-to-add-global-route-prefix-in-asp-net-core-3)

I copied the answer here:

`Startup.cs` class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(o => {
        o.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}");
    });
   // you need to install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning
    services.AddApiVersioning(o = >o.ReportApiVersions = true);
}
```

Now implement `UseGeneralRoutePrefix` method as below:

```cs
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, IRouteTemplateProvider routeAttribute)
    {
        opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention(routeAttribute));
    }

    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, string
        prefix)
    {
        opts.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute(prefix));
    }
}

public class RoutePrefixConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    private readonly AttributeRouteModel _routePrefix;

    public RoutePrefixConvention(IRouteTemplateProvider route)
    {
        _routePrefix = new AttributeRouteModel(route);
    }

    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var selector in application.Controllers.SelectMany(c => c.Selectors))
        {
            if (selector.AttributeRouteModel != null)
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(_routePrefix, selector.AttributeRouteModel);
            }
            else
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = _routePrefix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller add the version that you want using `ApiVersion(...)`, and you should specify `[ApiController]` else it wont work:

```cs
[ApiVersion( "1" )]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IN your Startp.cs you have the method "Configure".
Add this command there and should work. (Check if you already have this command there and just edit).
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "api/v1/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });`

And just keep the controller name in controller class.