# How to add global route prefix in asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-6.0

Unfortunately, advices for previous versions didn't work
[How to add global route prefix in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340979/how-to-add-global-route-prefix-in-asp-net-core-3)

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api"));
```

nor this one

```
public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, IRouteTemplateProvider routeAttribute)
    {
        opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention(routeAttribute));
    }

    public static void UseGeneralRoutePrefix(this MvcOptions opts, string 
    prefix)
    {
        opts.UseGeneralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute(prefix));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry silly me,
works fine

```
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/api/service"));
app.UseRouting();
```

Just add app.UseRouting();

I don't mind closing the question if you think that it is appropriate.

Comment: Is this still the right way to add a prefix globally? I have it in same exact order but no luck.

Comment: The way that is specified above works fine for my projects

Comment: I have this in my controller 
`[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1")]`

Does that impact/override the `UsePathBase`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but , I am using the similar  [Route("users/{userId}")] with [ApiController]